# What's the key to/for success?

Tags: prepositions

> What's the key to success?
>
> What's the key for success?

Which one of the 2 sentences above is correct, and why?

Comment: `What's the key to success?` sounds better to me. Perhaps `key to success` is an idiom, or perhaps there is a grammatical reason for it. I'll let somebody else try to explain the grammar ; )

Answer (score 3):

According to Ngram "the key to success" is preferred, "the key for success" is hardly used. [Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20key%20to%20success%2C%20the%20key%20for%20success&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20key%20to%20success%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%25)

I would say "the key to success" is analogue to "the key to the door".

Answer (score 2):

> Which one of the 2 sentences above is correct, and why?

**Both are correct.** How? I would try to explain with a brief example for both:

> What's the key for success?

This specifies `success` as a door. So, this question/statement asks for a key to that door.

> What's the key to success?

This specifies success as something on the other side of the door. So, this asks for a key of that door to get to the other side, which is `success`.

So, both makes equal sense. However, the latter one: **What's the key to success?** is used more often.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct and what you are looking to say.

> What's the key to success?

Meaning what is the one thing that is crucial to success. This is what you should use.

However...

> What's the key for success?

While is sort of scans it's poor English. A more commonly used phrase would be to say `What's the recipe for success?`. Which has a different meaning because it implies there's more than one thing needed for success.